# How to test if a line intersects a convex polygon?

Tags: geometry, 2d, polygon, computational-geometry, convex-polygon

Assume you are given the equation of a line (in 2d), and the equations of lines that form a convex polygon (the polygon could be unbounded). How do I determine if the line intersects the polygon?

[image: Intersection vs. no intersection]

Furthermore, are there computational geometry libraries where such tasks are pre-defined? I ask because I'm interested not just in the 2D version but n-dimensional geometry.

Answer (score 2):

For the 2D case, I think the problem simplifies a bit.

The line partitions the space into two regions.

If the polygon is present in only one of those regions, then the line does not intersect it.

If the polygon is present in both regions, then the line does intersect it.

So:

> Take any perpendicular to the line, making the intersection with the
>   line the origin.
>
> Project each vertex of the polytope onto the perpendicular.
>
> If those projections occur with both signs, then the polygon
>   intersects the line.

[Update following elexhobby's comment.]

Forgot to include the handling of the unbounded case.

I meant to add that one could create a "virtual vertex" to represent the open area. What we really need is the "direction" of the open area. We can take this as the mean of the vectors for the bounding edges of the open area.

We then treat the dot product of that direction with the normal and add that to the set of vertex projections.

Comment: Well not really right? The diagram on the left has the same sign for the dot product of all the vertices with the normal, yet it intersects the polyhedron.

Comment: @elexhobby. Thanks - quite right; I did have that in mind and then forgot to include it. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

In geometry, typically [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) a polygon is bounded.
What you are describing is usually called a polytope or a polyhedron [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope)

There are a few geometry libraries available, two that come to mind are boost (polygon) and CGAL. Generally, there is a distinct split between computational methods that deal with 2d,3d, and N-d - for obvious reasons.

For your problem, I would use a somewhat Binary Space Partitioning Tree approach. I would take the first line of your "poly" and trim the query line against it, creating a ray. The ray would start at the intersection of the two lines, and proceed in direction of the interior of the half-space generated by the first line of the "poly". Now I would repeat the procedure with the ray and the second line of the "poly". (this could generate a segment instead of ray) If at some point the ray (or now segment) origin lies on the outer side of a poly line currently considered and does not intersect it, then the answer is no - the line does not intersect your "poly". Otherwise it intersects. Take special care with various parallel edge cases. Fairly straight forward and works for multi-dimensional cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure, but I guess you can address this by use of duality. First normalize your line equations as `a.x+b.y=1`, and consider the set of points `(a,b)`.

These must form a convex polygon, and my guess is that the new line may not correspond to a point inside the polygon. This is readily checked by verifying that the new point is on the same side of all the edges. (If you don't know the order of the lines, first construct the convex hull.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from finite polygons.

To intersect polygon a line must intersect one of its edges. Intersection between line and an edge is possible only if two points lie on different sides from the line.

That can be easily checked with `sign(cross_product(Ep-Lp,Ld))` for two points of the edge. `Ep` - edge point, `Lp` - some point on the line, `Ld` - direction vector of the line, `cross_product(A,B)=Ax*By-Ay*Bx`.

To deal with infinite polygons we may introduce "infinite points". If we have a half infinite edge with point `E1` and direction `Ed`, its "second point" is something like `E1+infinity*Ed`, where `infinity` is "big enough number".

For "infinite points" the check will be slightly different:
`cross_product(Ep-Lp,Ld)=
=cross_product(E1+infinity*Ed-Lp,Ld)=
=cross_product(E1-Lp+infinity*Ed,Ld)=
=cross_product(E1-Lp,Ld)+cross_product(infinity*Ed,Ld)=
=cross_product(E1-Lp,Ld)+infinity*cross_product(Ed,Ld)`

If `cross_product(Ed,Ld)` is zero (the line is parallel to the edge), the sign will be determined by the first component. Otherwise the second component will dominate and determine the sign.