# Intersection of a (possibly unbounded) convex polygon with a halfplane

Tags: geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, intersection, cgal

This is a follow-up question to [How to test if a line intersects a convex polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687582/how-to-test-if-a-line-intersects-a-convex-polygon)

Lets say I am able to test if a line intersects a convex polygon or not (I'm still not sure what's the best method, and this question is linked with my difficulty). What I want to do is this: If I find that the line intersects the polygon, I want to maintain either the left or right polygon that is created. I'm not sure how to maintain the polygon object so that the above is easy to compute.

[image]

To summarize, given a polygon object and a line, how do I find the new polygon that is created by intersecting the halfplane-created-by-the-line with the polygon? Does CGAL or any other library have a ready-to-use function for this? If I have to code this from scratch, how should I maintain the polygon object?

Comment: I don't see how you're creating a new polyhedron here.  Do you mean that you're taking the intersection of a polyhedron with a *plane* rather than a line?  A single line isn't going to divide a polyhedron into two parts.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: you are right, my bad. I want to take the intersection of the polyhedron with either the left or right halfspace created by the line.

Comment: But how does a line create a halfspace?  You are working in three dimensions, right?

Comment: No. I'm working in 2d. By halfspace, I mean halfplane. Sorry, I'm not aware of the standard terminology used in CG.

Comment: Ah.  Then you probably want to rephrase your question to talk about polygons rather than polyhedra.

Comment: Maybe. But one of the answerers on my previous question said that polygons refer to bounded closed polygons. Unbounded polygons are referred to as polyhedra/polytopes. And I want to consider the unbounded case.

Comment: I suggest you ignore that answer: "polyhedron" pretty much always means a 3-dimensional object.  (polytope *is* more general, though).  But don't take my word for it: look up polyhedron any place and see what definition you get. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution using CGAL could be to use the [2D Boolean Operations on Nef Polygons](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_2/index.html). But for convex polygons, that might be an overkill. What bothers me is that you mention that you might want to use *unbounded* convex polygons. Without Nef polygons, I do not know if one can represent that in CGAL.